# How to handle translations for an ActiveModel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using Rails 3.1.1 and I would like to properly translate error messages for an `ActiveModel`. I don't know if overwriting the `i18n_scope` is the right way to solve my problem (or if there are other ways), but the [official documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Translation.html#method-i-i18n_scope) says:

> **i18n_scope()**
>
> Returns the i18n_scope for the class. Overwrite if you want custom
>   lookup.

... **how should I overwtite the `i18n_scope`?**

At this time I am getting a the following "alert":

```
# Note the 'activemodel' part
translation missing: de.activemodel.errors.models.my_class.attributes.message.blank

# I would like to "map" translations to 'de.activerecord.errors.messages.blank'
# as made for all other ActiveRecord classes in my application
```

---

My `ActiveModel` class is like the following:

```
class MyClass
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Dirty
  extend  ActiveModel::Naming
  extend  ActiveModel::Translation

  validates :name, :presence => true

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should be a class method, by analogy with [AR code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L818):

```
class MyClass
  include ActiveModel ...
  class << self
    def i18n_scope
      :activerecord
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked for me. Just for curiosity, do you know how is the yml structure for an activemodel model class?

Answer (score 1):

I have to apologise if my answer is wrong but I think the following link may be helpful for you.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html

This one may be can help you --> https://github.com/svenfuchs/activemodel-error

Or you may be try in file de.yml

de:

```
 activemodel:

   errors:

     my_class:

       attributes:

         message:

           blank: "your error description"
```

the last solution, you may be use this gem-->https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n
it will automatically translate the error messages for us.